# Visualforce page custom filter

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have an Object, lets say 'Resources'
Each object have type, lets say 'Contractors'
Each 'Contractor' may have sub-types A, B, C, D

I have visualforce page setup that outputs all 'Contractors' as a table, but I also want to have Sub-types dropdown with A, B, C, D values with option to filter Contractors (Lets say, I select 'A', page will be refreshed, and all contractors with sub-type A appear).

Type and Sub-type are related list (Type is controlling field for sub-type)

I would really appreciate for your help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had sort of the same problem and this is how I developed it.

your Visual force page:

```
 <apex:outputPanel id="PanelId">
    <apex:selectList size="1"  id="firstList" value="{!firstListVauleId}">              
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!UpdateSelectedFirstItem}" reRender="PanelId"/>
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!FirstListOptions}" />
      </apex:selectList>


      <apex:selectList size="1"  id="secondList" value="{!secondValueId}">              
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!SecondListOptions}" />
      </apex:selectList>

  </apex:outputPanel>
```

your apex class:

```
public String firstListVauleId {get;set;}
public String secondListVauleId {get;set;}
public List<SelectOption> getfirstListOptions()
{
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    // add items add needed. you can make database queries.
    return options;
}

public List<SelectOption> getsecondListOptions()
{
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    // add options based on the first list selection. you can make database queries.
    return options;
}


public void UpdateSelectedFirstItem()
{
    // do your stuff if you need to do anything upon changing the first dropdown selected item. 
}
```

Comment: Yes, it was good. Additionally I found this solution too http://titancronus.com/blog/2014/05/01/salesforce-acquiring-dependent-picklists-in-apex/